# PDO query not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The first code below works like a charm and the only difference between the 'postclass' table & the 'tpost' table in my database is the name.

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$country = "Thailand";
    if($keyword === "English" || $keyword === "อังกฤษ" || $keyword === "ภาษาอังกฤษ" || $keyword === "english"){
        if($keyword === "English" || $keyword === "english"){
            $sub_alt = "อังกฤษ";
        }
        if($keyword === "อังกฤษ" || $keyword === "ภาษาอังกฤษ"){
            $sub_alt = "English";
        }
    }

    if(isset($sub_alt)){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `tpost` WHERE `subject` LIKE :search OR `subject` LIKE :search2 AND `country` LIKE :country AND date >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    } else {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `tpost` WHERE `country` LIKE :country AND `subject` LIKE :search AND date >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    }

    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search','%'.$keyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if(isset($sub_alt)){
    $stmt->bindValue(':search2','%'.$sub_alt.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $stmt->bindValue(':country','%'.$country.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();


    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach( $result as $row){
    echo "WORKING";
    }

    } else { 
    echo "NO ROWS RETURNED";
    }
```

Sadly, this one below should do the same exact thing, but it's returning no rows. The tables in the database are set to InnoDB and UTF-8 and are identical in structure. The $_POST['keyword'] is also posting the correct data. Using Jquery $.post() method to post. It's something in this script that is causing the BELOW SCRIPT not to return rows. Tested on Firefox and Chrome. Anyone have an idea?

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$country = "Thailand";
    if($keyword === "English" || $keyword === "อังกฤษ" || $keyword === "ภาษาอังกฤษ" || $keyword === "english"){
        if($keyword === "English" || $keyword === "english"){
            $sub_alt = "อังกฤษ";
        }
        if($keyword === "อังกฤษ" || $keyword === "ภาษาอังกฤษ"){
            $sub_alt = "English";
        }
    }

    if(isset($sub_alt)){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `postclass` WHERE `subject` LIKE :search OR `subject` LIKE :search2 AND `country` LIKE :country AND `date` >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50";
    } else {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `postclass` WHERE `country` LIKE :country AND `subject` LIKE :search AND `date` >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50";
    }

    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search','%'.$keyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if(isset($sub_alt)){
    $stmt->bindValue(':search2','%'.$sub_alt.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $stmt->bindValue(':country','%'.$country.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();


    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "WORKING";
    }

    } else { 
    echo "NO ROWS RETURNED";
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's something in the $sql statement, but why would the 1st query work and not the 2nd query?

Comment: Also the $sub_alt variable and if statement is working correctly... Srsly has to be the $sql var...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Added this to my script to check error, completely forgot I'm still quite new to PHP MYSQL & PDO...

Though I must stress the importance of checking your errors by setting the attr of your handlers to ERRMODE...

The error stated that there was a conflict between my collation since one row was set on latin1_swedish_ci, after converting to utf8_unicode_ci the rows were now returning in the SQL... Sometimes the simplest stuff can catch you off-guard...